# XML Parsing in Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am using the below query to parse a HTML table as an XML in Oracle dynamically

```
SELECT ID,caption,amdtype AS Amendment_Reason
FROM
(
with tbl as
(
SELECT ID,xmltype('<html><body>'|| REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(Note AS VARCHAR(4000)),'<br>',''),'<br/>',''),'&','&amp;') || '</body></html>') AS xml_data
FROM TBL_EVENT
WHERE EVENT_TYPE='Amended note' 
AND to_Char(CREATED_DATE,'mm-yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1,'mm-yyyy') 
AND NUMBER NOT LIKE '%c%'
) 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.ID ORDER BY tbl.ID) AS Rankord,tbl.ID,
       
       x.caption,
       x.amdtype
FROM   tbl
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/html/body/table'
         PASSING tbl.xml_data
         COLUMNS
            caption VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'caption',
            amdtype VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'tr[1]/td[1]'
            
       ) x
WHERE x.caption='Amendment Reason'
)
```

It is working for some texts but I am getting the below error

**LPX-00243: element attribute value must be enclosed in quotes**

Since I am parsing it as XML dynamically I am not sure how to make the changes anyone please guide me how to do it

Comment: TL;DR: fix your data rather than trying to parse HTML as malformed XML. In this case, you need to make sure that you enclose the attribute values in quotes (exactly as the error message says).

Comment: @MT0 I am new to Oracle Database can you please explain what is TL;DR;

Comment: TL;DR means "too long, didn't read". But in this case its referring to the explanation rather than the question .... you can get a long and complicated answer on how to try fixing the input in an SQL query so it can be parsed. However, you'll then get another piece of HTML that is malformed as XML in a different way and it'll break again and you'll get another long and complicated answer on how to fix that. Don't try to go down this route. Instead, you need to fix your input so its well formed XML data and can be parsed by an XML parser rather than trying to parse something thats almost right.

Comment: @MT0 Yes you are right it will become a very complicated process also when we solve this another error arises if there is any special characters instead of XML parsing to get the value inside the HTML table tags is there any other way to read that data for your information the data is stored as CLOB

Comment: Why are you converting the data to XML just to query it with XML functions?  Why not share and example contents of the `NOTE` column and explain what you are trying to extract from the column?

Comment: Convert all your HTML to XHTML. You'll probably have to do this outside of the database; but then, when its well formed XML data, you'll be able to parse it using XML functions rather than trying to fix the HTML on the fly.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, I will try an alternative way of doing it